# How do I store my backup locally on an sql server using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, backup, sqlcmd

I am using:

```
$ sqlcmd -S gigbat -d FOD -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [FOD] TO DISK='C:\testDBbak1.bak'"
```

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Server gigbat, Line 1 Cannot open backup
>   device 'C:\testDBbak1.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is
>   denied.). Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server gigbat, Line 1 BACKUP
>   DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I assume it is trying to write to the server's c drive?

How can I specify my local c drive?

Comment: What happens if you run `md C:\foo` ?

Comment: I am in cygwin.  mkdir cygdrive/c/foo will create a new directory

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476508/which-user-account-is-running-sqlcmd-in-t-sql-script-without-u-and-p-option and try to find out which account and file is causing the problem. Procmon can filter for errors, then you will see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this message say it all?

```
Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)
```

This just means that the account being used to run the `sqlcmd` command does not have access to `C:\`. If it is a windows account, you can try granting required permissions on that drive.

Also storing in the root of the boot partition is not a good idea. Consider creating a folder, assigning required access privileges and write to that folder

Comment: I want to write to my local c drive - to which I already have access. Why is it saying denied?

Comment: i am admin. I am running from cygwin terminal which has access write to c drive